# I want to calculate total price according to selected options from dropdown list using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to calculate total price according to selected options from dropdown list using jquery.I have tried below code but its not working.Please help me how to solve it.I have mentioned few dropdowns with few options.I have edited script like this.Its working but when i change option from dropdown list it calculates both older nd newer option data-cost.
what changes I should do?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#cost").html("18.99");
        $("#CARVehicle").click(function () {
            $("#frontplaterowcar").show();
            $("#rearplaterowcar").show();
            $("#trailerrowcar").show();
            $("#rearplaterowmotor").hide();
            $("#cost").html("18.99");
        });
        $("#BIKEVehicle").click(function () {
            $("#frontplaterowcar").hide();
            $("#rearplaterowcar").hide();
            $("#trailerrowcar").hide();
            $("#rearplaterowmotor").show();
            $("#cost").html("22.99");
        });
        $("#frontplate").change(function () {
            var frontplateCost = 0;
            var frontplate = $("#frontplate");
            frontplate.find(":selected").each(function (index, element) {
                frontplateCost += $(this).data('cost');
                var total = parseFloat($("#cost").val()) + parseFloat(frontplateCost);
                $("#cost").val(total);
            });
        }).trigger('change');
        $("#rearplate").change(function () {
            var rearplateCost = 0;
            var rearplate = $("#rearplate");
            rearplate.find(":selected").each(function (index, element) {
                rearplateCost += $(this).data('cost');
                var total = parseFloat($("#cost").val()) + parseFloat(rearplateCost);
                $("#cost").val(total);
            });
        }).trigger('change');
        $("#trailer").change(function () {
            var trailerCost = 0;
            var trailer = $("#trailer");
            trailer.find(":selected").each(function (index, element) {
                trailerCost += $(this).data('cost');
                var total = parseFloat($("#cost").val()) + parseFloat(trailerCost);
                $("#cost").val(total);
            });
        }).trigger('change');
    });
</script>
<form id="platecontroller" action="">
    <table width="564" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5"
    style="margin-top: 5px" id="platebuilderbackground">
        <tr>
            <td width="164" align="right">Type of Vehicle:</td>
            <td width="400" align="left">
                <input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="CAR" id="CARVehicle" checked="checked"
                />CAR &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="BIKE"
                id="BIKEVehicle" />MOTORBIKE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="164" align="right">Registration:</td>
            <td width="400" align="left">
                <input name="regno" type="text" id="regno" value="" size="9" maxlength="7"
                style="text-transform: uppercase" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="frontplaterowcar">
            <td align="right">Front Plate:</td>
            <td align="left">
                <select name="frontplate" id="frontplate" style="width:380px;">
                    <option value="00001~1" data-cost="40">Standard Front Number Plate (520mm x 111mm) (GBP 9.99)</option>
                    <option
                    value="00002~9" data-cost="30">305mm x 152mm (12''x6'') American Import (GBP 13.99)</option>
                        <option value="00003~19"
                        data-cost="20">343mm x 165mm (13" x 6") (GBP 16.99)</option>
                        <option value="00004~13"
                        data-cost="50">330mm x 165mm (13" x 6.5") (GBP 14.99)</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="rearplaterowcar">
            <td align="right">Rear Plate:</td>
            <td align="left">
                <select name="rearplate" id="rearplate" style="width:380px;">
                    <option value="00109~109" data-cost="40">Standard Rear Number Plate (520mm x 111mm) (GBP 9.99)</option>
                    <option
                    value="00110~110" data-cost="40">298mm x 216mm 4x4 Square (GBP 13.99)</option>
                        <option value="00110~201"
                        data-cost="40">Standard Square 284mm x 203mm (GBP 13.99)</option>
                        <option value="00111~111"
                        data-cost="40">305mm x 152mm (12"x6") American Import (GBP 13.99)</option>
                        <option value="00112~112"
                        data-cost="40">176mm 557mm Aston Martin DB 9 (GBP 31.99)</option>
                        <option value="00113~113"
                        data-cost="40">612mm x 186mm Aston Martin Vanquish (GBP 31.99)</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="rearplaterowmotor" style="display:none;">
            <td align="right">Rear Plate:</td>
            <td align="left">
                <select name="rearplatemotor" id="rearplatemotor" style="width:380px;">
                    <option value="00096~96" data-cost="40">9.5" x 6.5" Motorcycle (GBP 13.99)</option>
                    <option value="00097~97" data-cost="40">9" x 7" Motorcycle (GBP 14.99)</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="trailerrowcar">
            <td height="23" align="right">Extra Rear (for trailer):</td>
            <td align="left">
                <select name="trailer" id="trailer" style="width:380px;">
                    <option value='0' data-cost="40">No Trailer Plate</option>
                    <option value='1' data-cost="40">Standard Rear (520mm x 111mm) Plain (no badges etc)</option>
                    <option value='2'
                    data-cost="40">Standard Rear (520mm x 111mm) with your selected styling</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<div id="pricedisp">Price:<span class="price">&pound;<span id="cost">0.00</span></span>
    <br
    /><a href="#" onclick="buy();"><img src="images/BuyNow_Button.jpg" alt="buy number plates" width="177" height="61" border="0" /></a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this for counting the sums of selected:

```
var frontplateCost = 0;
frontplate.find(":selected").each(function(index, element) {
    frontplateCost += $(this).data('cost');
});
```

Similar with the others.

Comment: Um.. I'm not entirely sure this will help you, now that I'm reading your code again. This would help if you could select multiple items...

Comment: This is not working dear. i can't get this idea.i want to calculate price from all dropdownlist.i m getting confused.please help me.